# Does the Java VM skip multiplication by zero?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, virtual

I would like to know if zero multiplies are avoided by the Java virtual machine. Thanks

Comment: Why should it avoid them in general? The result would be a different one. It might inline constant expressions and optimize those at compile time, though.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Java Language Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7.2), "every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed."

Therefore, even if the compiler or runtime could detect that one factor is zero, it still has to evaluate the other factor if the other one may have side effects.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement that a virtual machine do so, and in general I wouldn't expect such a thing; but virtual machines are allowed to make any optimizations that don't affect the observable behavior of a thread, so it's perfectly legal.

I think it's more likely, though, that a *compiler* would optimize away a multiplication if it can detect at compile-time that one of the operands is guaranteed to be zero. In that case, the multiplication would be removed long before it ever reached the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting that multiply by 0 is not always 0. e.g. for infinity and NaN, multiply by 0 gives NaN.

The javac compiler will optimise constant expressions.  If the compiler can determine the result is always a fixed value it performs the calculation at compile time.

The HotSpot compiler is very good at optimising code which doesn't do anything.  This doesn't mean it optimises every possible thing you can imagine, just common use cases it can detect and multiplying by zero may or may not be one of them.  It also may vary between JVM implementations.  In short you shouldn't rely on it either way.